# 411 content length required WebAPI WebHook

Tags: iis, http2, http-1.1, http-content-length, http-status-code-411

[image]

I have a broblem when trying to request my dotnet API with (Http post with empty body) alway i receive (status code 411 content length required)

Hi

What's the best whay to configure the c# WebAPI to accept all incomming Http post methode with an empty body